# What practical algorithms exist for simplifying sampled multidimensional curves

Tags: math, 3d, curve, simplification

For 2-dimensional sampled curves (an array of 2D points) there exists the [Rahmer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) which only keeps "important" points. It works by calculating the perpendicular distance of each point (or sample) to a line that connects the first and the last point of. If the maximum distance is larger than a value epsilon the point is kept and the array is split into 2 parts. For both parts the operation is repeated (maximal perpendicular distance, if larger than epsilon etc.) The smaller epsilon the more detail is kept.

I am trying to write a function that can also do this for higher arrays of higher dimensional points. But I am unsure how to define distance. Or if this is actually a good idea.
I guess there exist lots of complicated and elegant algorithms that fit the curves to beziers and NURBS and what not. But are there also relatively simple ones?
I would prefer not to use beziers, but simply to identify "important" N-dimensional points.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend your 2D algorithm using algebra and the L2 norm. Let's say you want to calculate the distance from a point X to a line segment PQ (where X, P and Q are defined as N-dimensional vectors).

[image]

First you can calculate the vector "proj" as:

[image]

Then, the distance is the module of the vector V = PX-proj.

For this calculation you only need the dot product between vectors, and that is well defined for N-dimensional spaces.

Using this approach I have successfuly used Rahmer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm in 3D.